# Virtual inheritance crashes application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crash, virtual-inheritance

The following code crashes (Access violation error) because I used virtual inheritance.
AFAIK virtual inheritance solves the Diamond problem by forcing use of a single instance of a class. In this case the `Derived` class inherits only one instance of `IObject`so there should be no problem, but it crashes.

```
class IObject
{
public:
    virtual int getType()=0;
};
class Base : public IObject
{
protected:
    int val;
public:
    Base() { val = 1; }
    virtual int getType();
};
int Base::getType() { return val; }

class Derived : public virtual Base //If I remove the virtual keyword here problem is solved.
{
public:
    Derived() { val = 2; }
};

int getVal( void* ptr ) 
{
    return ((IObject*)ptr)->getType();
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = new Derived();
    cout << getVal(ptr) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use virtual inheritance?

Comment: I don't. I was re-factoring my code and eventually virtual inheritance became unnecessary. However I didn't notice it before the crash happened, then I removed it. Still I'm curious about the cause.

Comment: There is no diamond problem here!!!

Comment: @barakmanos I know. What I don't understand is why it is causing a crash.

Comment: Your code ran fine, when i tried it using the IObject* instead of void and removed the casting. I tried on VS2010 and Ideone C+11

Comment: @sajas Yes, I know that, the same is true for VS2008. But that is the case in the actual code.

Comment: I tried the code with compile online (GCC 4.7.2) and it crashes as explained in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the chain of casts is incorrect: `Derived* -> void* -> IObject*` is undefined behavior resulting from mixing C and C++ concepts. More specifically, the rules around `void*` are inherited from C without any adaptation for objects and hierarchy.

The solution, therefore, is to make sure that any cycle through `void*` is a `T -> void* -> T` cycle: always through the same type. Thus, in your situation, you need `Derived* -> IObject* -> void* -> IObject*`.

---

To understand why `virtual` inheritance causes an issue, you have to understand the specifics of how it is represented *concretely* (which is implementation-defined). Let's have a look at examples of **possible in-memory representations** (loosely based on the Itanium ABI).

A linear non-virtual hierarchy is implemented as if by composition:

```
struct Base { int a; };
struct Derived: Base { int b; };
struct SuperDerived: Derived { int c; };

+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
^~~~~~~~~ Derived
    ^~~~~ Derived specific
^~~~~         Base

+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
^~~~~~~~~~~~~ SuperDerived
        ^~~~~ SuperDerived specific
^~~~~~~~~     Derived
^~~~~         Base
```

In this case, `&derived == &base` and `&superderived == &derived` in general (note: if one layer does not have a virtual table and the next layer does, then this falls off the roof).

A hierarchy with multiple bases

```
struct Base1 { int a; };
struct Base2 { int b; };
struct Derived: Base1, Base2 { int c; };

+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
^~~~~~~~~~~~~ Derived
        ^~~~~ Derived specific
    ^~~~~     Base2
^~~~~         Base1
```

In this case, `&derived == &base1` but `&derived != &base2`, so already we note that a base class does not necessarily have the same address that its derived class.

And finally, let's push virtual inheritance in:

```
struct Object { int a; };
struct Base1: virtual Object { int b; };
struct Base2: virtual Object { int c; };
struct Derived: Base1, Base2 { int d; };

+---+---+
| b | a |
+---+---+
^~~~~~~~~ Complete Base1
^~~~~     Base1 specific
    ^~~~~ Object

+---+---+
| c | a |
+---+---+
^~~~~~~~~ Complete Base2
^~~~~     Base2 specific
    ^~~~~ Object

+---+---+---+---+
| b | c | d | a |
+---+---+---+---+
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Complete Derived
        ^~~~~     Derived specific
^~~~~             Incomplete Base1
    ^~~~~         Incomplete Base2
            ^~~~~ Object
```

The challenge here is that a single instance of the virtual base should be shared between all potential bases. Since only the complete object knows which bases will be involved, a simple choice is to let the complete object be responsible for the placement of the virtual base (which it places at the tail) and have the virtual table provide the machinery to navigate, at runtime, from `Object` to a derived class.

However, note that in the case of how our design `&base1 != &object`, `&base2 != &object` and `&derived != &object` because `object` is placed at the tail.

That is why it is important to perform the casts using the **C++ machinery** which knows how to statically or dynamically (depending on the situation) compute the pointer adjustment necessary when going from one base to another.

*Note: the C++ machinery knows whether the computation is static or dynamic and for example `static_cast<Base1*>(&object)` is a compile-time error, a `dynamic_cast` is necessary here.*

Comment: Very well put, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @atoMerz: I am glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 3):

The actual crash comes from using void* and casting in combination with multiple inheritance (in this case just using virtual inheritance).  As James Kanze pointed out, because casting to void* and then not casting back to the original type is undefined behavior, anything is possible.

When using c++ style casting, the pointer is actually changed to enable working with multiple inheritance.  By using c style (and void*), the compiler can't do that, so you are accessing IObject with a different virtual table (as shown in the answer of barak manos).

A working solution (without the void*):

```
#include <iostream>

class IObject
{
public:
    virtual int getType()=0;
};
class Base : public IObject
{
protected:
    int val;
public:
    Base() { val = 1; }
    virtual int getType();
};
int Base::getType() { return val; }

class Derived : public virtual Base
{
public:
    Derived() { val = 2; }
};

int getVal( IObject* ptr ) 
{
    return ptr->getType();
}

int main()
{
    IObject* ptr = new Derived();
    std::cout << getVal(ptr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be very exact: the only thing you can do with a `void*` is cast it back to the type used to create it.  Here, it was created from a `Derived*`, so casting it to an `IObject*` and using it is undefined behavior.  (For the reasons you cite; I'm not trying to correctly you, but only point out the formal justification which allows this behavior.)

Comment: And you might add that although it seems to work without the `virtual`, it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze `Derived` inherits `IObject`, So I should be able to cast pointer to one another. I don't understand Why it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @stefaanv printing out doesn't help me. The value of ptr in function is the same as its value in `main`. So I think it should work.

Comment: @atoMerz The `Derived` instance and its `IObject` subobject don't necessarily start at the same address.

Comment: Is there any way I can get back inheritance information after casting to `void*`?

Comment: @atoMerz Casting `Derived*` to `IObject*` is valid.  Casting `Derived` to `void*`, then to `IObject*` is undefined behavior.  Precisely for the implementation reasons that @stefaanv explains.

Comment: @atoMerz By casting back to what was converted to `void*`.  The usual solution in such cases is to explicitly convert the results of `new Derived` to an `IObject*`, before assigning it to `void*`.  (And we avoid `void*` except in cases like interfacing to a system routine like `pthread_create`, which requires it for a call-back.)

Comment: I also checked and it is not the pointer value which I assumed because this is the case for multiple inheritance.  But as @JamesKanze correctly pointed out: it is UB in the first place.  I was focusing on the technical details.  I assume that the compiler is still confused about the virtual table.

Comment: Try the following: `Derived* pD = new Derived; IObject* pI = pD; std::cout << "pD* = " << pD << ", pI* = " << pI << std::endl;`.  The reason the standard makes it undefined behavior is because once you convert to `void*`, and information about where to find what in the object has been lost.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that might help you to understand the problem:

```
void* ptr = new Derived();
IObject* ptr1 = (IObject*)ptr;
IObject* ptr2 = new Derived();
IObject* ptr3 = new Derived();
```

When you view the `IObject` pointers in the debugger, this is more or less what you see:

[image]

Each instance of class `Derived` has an additional member variable (implicitly added by the compiler to the definition of the class), which points to the virtual-function table (aka V-Table) of the class. With the Visual Studio debugger, you can view it in any such instance under the name `__vfptr`.

As you can see in the image above, `ptr2->__vfptr` and `ptr3->__vfptr` are correctly pointing to address 0x01236834, where the V-Table of the class is located. The value of the first entry in this table is 0x012310f0, which is the address of function `Base::getType`.

On the other hand, `ptr1->__vfptr` is pointing to address 0x0123683C. The value of "the first entry in this table" is 0x00000000, which is obviously **not** the address of any function, hence the memory access violation that you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

The crash is caused by the reinterpret_cast.

```
    void* ptr = new Derived();
```

is actually

```
void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new Derived());
```

When you do this, ptr has no knowledge of what it is pointing to.  When you do

```
return ((IObject*)ptr)->getType();
```

it means

```
return (reinterpret_cast<IObject*>(ptr))->getType();
```

This calls IObject::getType, which is not defined: hence the crash.  To get around it, use IObject* instead of void*

```
IObject* ptr = new Derived();
...
int getval(IObject* ptr)
{
    return ptr->getType();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can cast it back after it has been cast to `void*`?

Comment: Not that I know of - are there lots of virtual functions declared in IObject?  Can you split it off into a different file?

Comment: @atoMez convert first to the type that you want out of the `void*`.  **then** convert to `void*`.  Doing anything else is dangerous, even if it works: usually UB outside of some narrow cases.  You need to treat conversion to-from `void*` with more care.  "It works" is not sufficiently good, as often UB is "it works": crashes and fragile code that breaks far from the change are what happens -- I avoid implicit-cast-to-`void*`, and try to isolate to-from `void*` in my code.